# Javascript not triggered when supposed to

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

How come the Javascript isValidEmailAndEqual isn't triggered when submitting the form:

```
echo("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>
<!--

function isValidEmailAndEqual() {
regExp = /^[^@]+@[^@]+$/;


if((document.subscribe.email1.value.search(regExp) == -1) || !isEqual(document.subscribe.email1.value, document.subscribe.email2.value)) 
   { 
   //alert(isEqual(document.subscribe.email1.value, document.subscribe.email2.value))
       alert('Incorrect entered email addresses. They must be valid e-mail addresses and equal.');
      return false; 
   } 

   //document.subscribeForm.submit();

return true; 
}


-->
</script>");

echo ("<div class='subscribe'>
     <h4>Subscribe</h4>
     <p>Subscribe to iAndApp's newsletter in order to get information about new and updated iPhone games and iPhone applications, that has been released by iAndApp. </p>
     <form action='subscription.php' name='subscribe' method='post'  onsubmit='return isValidEmailAndEqual()'>
        <p class='formlabel'>Förnamn</p> <input type='text' name='first_name'/><br/>
        <p class='formlabel'>Efternamn</p> <input type='text' name='surname'/> <br/>
        <p class='formlabel'>E-mail</p> <input type='text' name='email1'/><br/>
        <p class='formlabel'>Repeat e-mail</p> <input type='text' name='email2'/> <br/>
        <input class='inputsubmit' type='submit' value='Subscribe'/>
     </form>
</div>");
```

Firebug tells me there is no javascript on the page.

I have tried both with and without comments and prefix the closing comment tag.

What I do, which may matter, is loading the below content from a server and than adding to a div-tag. The content is presented, but still the scripts doesnt' work. I have also tried to include the scripts on the main/parent-page (the page loading content and adding it to a div) where I have other scripts that works (triggered by component in the main/parent page though).

Thank you in advance!

Comment: the ending comment should be prefixed with `//`, look at my answer

Comment: Made no difference. Added some info about how I load the page: "What I do, which may matter, is loading the below content from a server and than adding to a div-tag. The content is presented, but still the scripts doesnt' work. I have also tried to include the scripts on the main/parent-page (the page loading content and adding it to a div) where I have other scripts that works (triggered by component in the main/parent page though). "

Comment: @Nicsoft: That's a pretty significant difference from what you posted. Can you please update your question with the code that is actually being used?

Answer (score 1):

It should be
`echo("<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'>

<!--

//your code here, obviously not commented

//-->

</script>`

FYI, http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.3.2

Comment: commenting out `-->` just hides `-->` from the javascript parser (see the link you posted).Without commenting it out, wouldn't it just be a line of invalid JS, and therefore the page would have an error but the function would work fine?

Comment: That's not to say you shouldn't comment it out - you should, because otherwise it will generate a JS error (upvote!). I'm just not convinced that is the reason the function is not running for him, since it is working fine as-posted for me.

Comment: It didn't change. Please se my update question, added som more info.

Comment: @Cam, you are right, sorry have been away for a while, it seems I would ask @Nicsoft to start with stone age debugging techniques, just use `<script>` tag w/out extra params/attribs, no commenting and a plain alert. And @Nicsoft please do update the code you have used.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, they are triggered. The following HTML (exactly as outputted by your script) causes the function to trigger in both firefox 5 and chrome. As a sidenote, you probably do not need the html comments (`<!--` and `-->`). That's an practice that is generally no longer necessary since browsers that do not support javascript simply ignore everything within the  tags.

That being said if you must have the html comments, comment out the `-->` to avoid it triggering a JS error (as Kumar explains).

```
<script language='javascript' type='text/javascript'> 
<!--

function isValidEmailAndEqual() {
regExp = /^[^@]+@[^@]+$/;


if((document.subscribe.email1.value.search(regExp) == -1) || !isEqual(document.subscribe.email1.value, document.subscribe.email2.value)) 
   { 
   //alert(isEqual(document.subscribe.email1.value, document.subscribe.email2.value))
       alert('Incorrect entered email addresses. They must be valid e-mail addresses and equal.');
      return false; 
   } 

   //document.subscribeForm.submit();

return true; 
}


-->
</script><div class='subscribe'> 
     <h4>Subscribe</h4> 
     <p>Subscribe to iAndApp's newsletter in order to get information about new and updated iPhone games and iPhone applications, that has been released by iAndApp. </p> 
     <form action='subscription.php' name='subscribe' method='post'  onsubmit='return isValidEmailAndEqual()'> 
        <p class='formlabel'>FÃ¶rnamn</p> <input type='text' name='first_name'/><br/> 
        <p class='formlabel'>Efternamn</p> <input type='text' name='surname'/> <br/> 
        <p class='formlabel'>E-mail</p> <input type='text' name='email1'/><br/> 
        <p class='formlabel'>Repeat e-mail</p> <input type='text' name='email2'/> <br/> 
        <input class='inputsubmit' type='submit' value='Subscribe'/> 
     </form> 
</div>
```

Comment: It may have someting to do how I load the content. Please see my update question.